# How can I restore the position of a VS Code panel after moving it to a different location?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what configuration / extension did I turned on, but every time I open my terminal on VS Code, the "debug console" also comes up after it, in a split view screen:

[image]

I also can't disable it when I right click on it:

[image]

What should I do to turn it off and only see my terminal, every time I press my terminal hotkey?

Comment: drag the debug console panel to the new location or select command **Reset View Locations**

Comment: **Reset Location** is a good first, otherwise you can delete the workspace `.db` file, locate the UUID of the workspace

Comment: @rioV8 wow thanks! dragged it under the side bar stack after outline and timeline! now I can rest at peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- Right click the title bar of the panel whose position you want to restore, and in the context menu that appears, click "Reset Location".
- Click and drag the title bar of the panel that you moved elsewhere to go anywhere in the tab strip of the main panel.
- If you want to take the nuclear route, you can also use the `View: Reset View Locations` command in the command palette. (this will reset *all* panels and views to their default locations).